# overlapping of two select boxes

Tags: html, css

I have two select boxes in `HTML`, one below the other.

- The first select box is normal
- The second selectbox is by default opened(means options are displayed without click)

Now when I click on the first `select box` it's content moves behind the other `select box`.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <li>
        <label class="labelwid" for="partner">Select partner*</label>
            <select name="partner" id="partner" class="validate[required] text-input selectbox customselect" style="width:275px !important">
                <option value="{partnerno}">{partnername}</option>
            </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="fl"><b>Market Application</b><br />
            <select name="markappcategory[]" id="category" multiple="multiple" class="validate[required] text-input  selectbox" style="width:230px !important">
                {categoryname_html_m}
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
</form>
```

Custom select is a `jquery` plugin for custom inputs.

**CSS `first select box`**

```
position:absolute; top:40px; padding:2px 0 5px 0; left:0; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; z-index:1000; background:#fff; border:1px solid #d1cdcd; border-top:none; font-size:15px; width:265px; left:4px; height:100px;
```

Comment: Can we see the code? of what you've already tried?

Comment: I've shown the second selectbox list by default using jquery.

Comment: Can we see the `css` too? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-indexes` are compared on the same level, this means that two elements with different parents will be z-indexed in relation with their parent's z-indexes, here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/5tLrz/. When I encounter this kind of problems it usually is because of that.

Comment: His problem is not with div tag on top. Using Z index you can make certain div (oe any tag) on top. Here, its due to position issue which is not set properly.

Comment: I assume it is `z-index` issue because he sais 'behind' and not 'bellow'.

Comment: May be he misused it. He is using a form. In form it does not make sense if you hide some element behind another using z index.

Comment: Yes, I've changed z-index property of 1st select box with a higher value than the z-index of 2nd select box. It's working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the `position` in the style tag. Are you doing it in your CSS? if so, post the css code. Refer: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp for more.

Comment: can you update that code in the question. You are making that mistake only.

Comment: @Tushar the position might be overwritten by a `parent` element. Try adding `position: (some position here) !important;`.

Comment: Here's what i've applied to first select box.                                                                         position:absolute; top:40px; padding:2px 0 5px 0; left:0; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; z-index:1000; background:#fff; border:1px solid #d1cdcd; border-top:none; font-size:15px; width:265px; left:4px; height:100px;

Comment: For which class are you using this css?

Comment: I have posted the answer in another answer since there was no enough space. try that and do let me know about the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form> 
    <li> 
        <label class="labelwid" for="partner" style="position: absolute; top: 10; left:10;" >Select partner*</label> 
        <select name="partner" id="partner" class="validate[required] text-input selectbox customselect" style="position: absolute; top: 10; left:200; width:275px !important"> 
            <option value="{partnerno}">{partnername}</option> 
        </select> 
    </li>   
    <li> 
        <div class="fl">
            <label style="position: absolute; top: 200; left:10;"><b>Market Application</b></label><br /> <select name="markappcategory[]" id="category" multiple="multiple" class="validate[required] text-input selectbox" style="position: absolute; top: 200; left:200; width:230px !important"> {categoryname_html_m} </select> 
        </div> 
    </li>
```

Try this code only. It works fine for me. change your position according to your need.