# CSS z-index not working with child-elements

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

Ive tried for a personal project to do menus, that are opened on highest layer (z-index 3) so they overlay my board, but the header in which they are is at lowest layer (z-index 1), so the board was assigned to mid-layer (z-index 2).
Logically this looks fine to me, but menu is displayed as it was below z-index 2...
Ive ran out of ideas how to fix that.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#header {
  width: 512px;
  height: 256px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
div>ul {
  width: 512px;
  height: 128px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: blue;
}
ol {
  width: 480px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: 32px 16px 0 16px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<ol>
</ol>
```

[CodePen Sample](http://codepen.io/PaHell/pen/mVGJxd)

Comment: what's the problem here?

Comment: Please include your code inside the question, not just a link formatted as code. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @DomlThe-Bread Basically the blue `<ul>` should show above the green `<ol>`, but the rest of the red `#header` should be behind it

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996157/overlapping-of-two-select-boxes/14997771#14997771

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the z index of child elements is always the z index of the parent element
you can only position the elements on same layers. 
So in your case every element inside `#header` will be on `z-index 1` compared to the `<ol>` which is `z-index 2`.

`z-index: 3` from the unsorted list would only work within the `#header` if the `<ol>` would also be inside that container.

```
<div id="header">
   <ul></ul>
   <ol>
   </ol>
</div>
```

So what you want to achieve is not possible in this case. you would have to change your html structuring. or set the z-index from `#header` higher than the z index from `<ol>`

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `ul` parent(which is on the same level with `ol`) has `z-index:1`

If you put `ul` and `ol` on the same level it'll work as expected